# A opção '--resolveJsonModule' não pode ser especificada sem a estratégia de resolução de módulo de 'nó'.ts

Tags: typescript, next.js, módulo-ecmascript

Toda vez que aciono o comando `npm run dev` o Next.Js sobrescreve o `tsconfig.json` e coloca a opção `"resolveJsonModule": true`, só que aparece um erro insuportável no arquivo que nunca sai`A opção '--resolveJsonModule' não pode ser especificada sem a estratégia de resolução de módulo de 'nó'.ts`. Já reiniciei o VSCode, o Computador, setei pra false, exclui a opção, mas ela é sempre reescrita e nunca sai esse erro.

```
We detected TypeScript in your project and reconfigured your tsconfig.json file for you. Strict-mode is set to false by default.
```

The following mandatory changes were made to your tsconfig.json:

```
    - resolveJsonModule was set to true (to match webpack resolution)
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema, resolvi colocando este campo `"moduleResolution": "node"` , no arquivo tsconfig.json, dentro do objeto "compilerOptions".

[image: tsconfig.json]